# Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus Displays wrong status (Microsoft Exchange)

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

When I execute the Exchange command in powershell, and below command is executed before executing Exchange command.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.E2010
```

The "Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus" command can display the correct status if I execute it with a user in Exchange "Organization Management" Group.

```
Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus | FL name,status
Name   : DB01\SERVER0246
Status : Mounted
```

But when I use a user in a group which has same roles as "Organization Management" Group.The result will look like below:

```
Name   : DB01\SERVER0246
Status : ServiceDown
```

I have searched for a long time on Internet, but I cannot find any explanation.
Is there a way that I can get the right result for "Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus" command without adding the user in "Organization Management" Group?

Comment: This would be on-topic at ServerFault, as Exchange management cmdlet behavior questions are not about programming.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have posted the issue at ServerFault.